# awk ''attempt to use scalar `SUM' as array''

Tags: awk

I just learning awk, here is my problem:

*test.awk*

```
BEGIN {
  SUM=0
  AVE=0
  COUNT=0
}

{
  for(COUNT+=3; COUNT<=22; COUNT=COUNT+1)
    SUM[NR]=SUM[NR]+$COUNT
}

END {
  for(COUNT=1; COUNT<=N; COUNT=COUNT+1)
    SUM[COUNT]
}
```

When I run:

```
awk -f test.awk hello
```

I get this error:

> awk: cmd. line:2: (FILENAME=hello FNR=1) fatal: attempt to use scalar `SUM' as array

Please tell me what's happen and how should I to correct it.

Comment: Its better you give us your data and what you like to get out of it.

Comment: Remove the useless `BEGIN` section and change `COUNT=COUNT+1` -> `COUNT++` and `SUM[NR]=SUM[NR]+$COUNT` -> `SUM[NR] += $COUNT`. Also, don't use all-upper-case variable names as that's for built-in variables and figure out what `N` needs to be in the loop in your END section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SUM=0
```

This tells awk that `SUM` is a scalar, in this case the number zero.

```
SUM[NR]=...
```

This tells awk that you want to use `SUM` as an array. But you've already told it that `SUM` is `0`, you can't use `0[NR]`.